# Method Overloading Example

Tags: java

*Will this is a example of method overloading in java?
Ex 1:

```
public int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
public float add(float a,float b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

- Different return type .
Ex 2:

```
public int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
private float add(float a,float b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

- Different return type and access modifier
Ex 3:

```
public int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
private int add(int a,int b,int c)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

- Different access modifer
*

Comment: I don't think you can overload with numeric types because of ambiguity between lower numbers

Comment: Have you tried to create a source code at all? The compiler would tell you if such overloads are possible in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all examples it ll be treated as a method overloading.

Overloaded methods are differentiated by the number and the type of the arguments passed into the method. In the code sample, `draw(String s)` and `draw(int i)` are distinct and unique methods because they require different argument types.

You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell them apart.

The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload methods as long as they have different method signatures (different number or type of method parameters). However, Java doesn't consider return type to be part of the method signature, so you can't have the same number and type of parameters and have a different return type, as the compiler could not tell them apart.

All of your examples work.